# Persistent Java Databases

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm working on a quiz-type application in Java. I'm thinking of a database to hold questions, their difficulty and 4 multi-choice items, perhaps also with the option for the user to create their own questions in the database for their friends to attempt. The code I've wrote currently works within my IDE:

```
public class Database {
    Connection conn=null;
    String url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Millionaire";
    String username="luke";
    String password="bigwood";
    private ArrayList<String> arrayGot = new ArrayList<>();

    Database(){
        try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
        } 
        catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("SQL Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getQuestions(int difficulty) throws SQLException{
        arrayGot.clear();
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement( );
            String SQLCommand ="select * from LUKE.QUESTIONS where difficulty="+difficulty;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQLCommand );
            while(rs.next()){
                String question = rs.getString("Question");
                arrayGot.add(question);
                question = rs.getString("Answer1");
                arrayGot.add(question);
                question = rs.getString("Answer2");
                arrayGot.add(question);
                question = rs.getString("Answer3");
                arrayGot.add(question);
                question = rs.getString("Answer4");
                arrayGot.add(question);
            }

        return arrayGot;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to know however is there a simple way to make this work outside of my IDE (NetBeans). Once built I'd like the database to be both readable and writable on any computer that the .jar ends up on. What would be the best way to implement this?

Cheers in advance, 
Luke.

Comment: I thing you are not setting your jar class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up Derby to run in [embedded mode](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html), this will allow you to run independently of other services. Keep in mind that you will need to handle initialization of the database tables from within your code.

Comment: Right, so this will let me transfer a database with the app, or do I need to re-create thousands (potentially) of cells every time I want to use the database?

Comment: AFAIK you can distribute a pre-made database, as the on-disk format is stable. You could also distribute compressed SQL dumps, or fetch them from the network (auto-update?).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevdvlp17453.html link and it will show you how to set up Derby as a directory based or classpath url

e.g.

```
jdbc:derby:C:/demo/sample
or
jdbc:derby:classpath:/myDB
```

Answer (score -1):

Sample code for connectivity

```
public static Connection Connect(){


try {

    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

    System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;

}

System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

Connection connection = null;

try {

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "YOUR JDBC URL", "USERNAME",
            "PASSWORD");

} catch (SQLException e) {

    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;

}



return connection;
```

}

try with your database properties